# Custom MTOM binding and Max upload size

Tags: wcf, file-upload, wcf-binding, mtom

I'm using the binding configuration below for my upload service,

```
<binding name="FileUploadSTSBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false"
                    keyEntropyMode="ServerEntropy"
                    requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
          </security>
          <mtomMessageEncoding/>
          <httpsTransport 
            transferMode="Streamed" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
```

But with this setting, I'm not able to upload big files like more than 1mb, server response is bad request.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the maxRequestLength attribute as well for the upload to work. It can here found in the web.config file here:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime>
```

Check that the IIS app pool identity has the right to write to the temp folder to be able to temporarily store the incoming data.

Comment: I've set the max value for maxRequestLength attribute, but still it's not working. Server returns a bad request, whenever I try to upload a large file.

Comment: It's hosted on IIS with Windows 2003 server.I've verified the app pool identity has the right to store data. Any settings missing in the binding?