# WCF Error MTOM Encoding + sending large data from client to service

Tags: .net, wcf, mtom

I am trying out [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209%28VS.100%29.aspx) from MSDN.

I try to send a file by making use of FileStream and WCF.

When I send small files with only a few bytes I get the output. But when I try to send across a file of a few MB I get an error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error (The request was aborted: The request was cancelled).

I have changed the max values within the binding and set it to bigger value. I have also changed the timeout. I have enabled tracing, but there is no error to be found in the trace.

I am not able to figure out the issue. Can anyone help?

here is the service .. config file

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsHttpServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="customWsHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>       
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="MTOMUploadService.UploadService" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint contract="MTOMUploadService.IUploadService" binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding" />
  </service>
</services>
```

here is the client config....

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IUploadService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://machinename:4575/MTOMUploadService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IUploadService"
            contract="IUploadService" name="WSHttpBinding_IUploadService">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="machinename" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Did you change the message size on both client & service bindings?

Comment: That helps. At first sight I don't see/spot any problems with your configuration. You'll have to dig a little deeper on the CommunicationException and tell us about the relevant bits of the stack trace etc. In addition it could help to enable tracing, and inspect if the messages that are sent are in fact MTOM encoded.

Comment: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException-The Underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. --> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed:A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the remote host.--> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.                 @Jeroen here goes the exception

Comment: I also get another exception - System.SeviceModel.CommunicationException - An error occured while sending data over the HTTP channel when I try to send a 15 MB file

Comment: It may be better to post the relevant exception info in the question, it may be of use to anyone trying to answer it. In addition, tell us how you're hosting the service? There may be a limitation there. Furthermore, can you be specific about where the threshold lies (MB-wise)?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen I am hosting this in IIS. and the file size which I am talking about starts from 2+MB range.. less than 1 MB i get proper result.

Comment: Sounds like an IIS limitation, perhaps? Try self-hosting the service, see if that solves anything. Maybe[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3886055/419956) can also help?

Comment: any solution about it with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 2):

Just put this into your wcf web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```